# ruby how could i make this factorization recursive till i end with a binary number?

Tags: ruby, recursion, factors

i have this code, basically first i factorize for example the number 28 to:
[2,2,7]
and then i make a list of prime numbers and find the index of each factor in that list, so 2 is prime number with index 0 and 7 prime number with index 2 so it ends up like this:
[[0],[0],[2]]
with which another recursion would be:
[[0],[0],[[0]]]
which tranlated to binary would be:
1101101110111

but im stuck on this:

```
require 'prime'

def f(n)

    Prime.prime_division(n).flat_map { |factor, power| [factor] *   power }

end

n=rand(10000)

puts n

f=f (n)

require 'prime'

@list=Prime.take(10000)

g=[]

j=0

f.each do |j|


if j>10

    i=f(@list.index(j))

    g.push i

    i=[]

else

    g.push j

end

end

print g
```

Comment: For recursion, you need a method, and it needs to call itself. Did you try anything else?

Comment: i just started ruby two days ago so i really know very little about it, so far ive just been programming in small basic which is very different and anarchic

Comment: Where does this question come from? Is it an assignment?

Comment: no im learning programing by myself for fun cause i love maths, i set myself the objective of building a compressor of info and this is taking me to cryptography and prime factors

Comment: Does this "compression" has a name?

Comment: First primes are `2,3,5,7` so 7's index is 3.

Comment: no it ocurred to me while thinking of methods to compress info, the index of a prime number  is always gonna be smaller than the number itself, but how could you factorize moby dick book with todays computers accounting its a number in base 26(the letters)

Answer (score 2):

You want to learn, so I won't do all the work for you.

## Step 1

Please write those 3 methods :

```
def get_factors(integer)
  # return an Array of Integers:
  # get_factors(28) -> [2,2,7]
end

def get_factor_index(prime)
  # return the index of prime in Prime.all :
  # 2 -> 0
  # 7 -> 2
end

def array_to_binary(nested_array)
  # convert nested_array (with 0s in leaves) to binary
  # [[0],[0],[[0]]] -> "1101101110111"
  # Hint : Use Array#to_s, and then String#gsub 3 times to convert ',' to '', and '[' or ']' to 1
end
```

and come back once you're done. We'll work on the recursion.

## Step 2

I modified a bit your answer just a bit. To make it clearer, I tried to use different names for variables and methods. Also, the last line of a method is returned automatically by Ruby. You don't need to define an extra variable. Methods could probably be written more efficiently but I didn't want you to not recognize your code.

Your `get_factor_index` does more than what I asked for BTW. I'm not sure we can use it like this :

```
require "prime"

def get_factors(integer)
  Prime.prime_division(integer)
end

def nested_array(factors)
  factors.flat_map { |factor, power| [factor] *   power }
end

def get_factor_index(nested_array)
  list=Prime.take(10000)
  temp=[]
  nested_array.each do |i|
    p = list.index(i)
    temp.push(p)
  end
  temp
end

def array_to_binary(array)
  temp=array.to_s
  temp=temp.gsub("[","1")
  temp=temp.gsub("]","1")
  temp=temp.gsub(",","")
  temp.gsub(" ","")
end
```

Now, please write a method that uses all the above ones, converting 512 to "10000000001". I'm not sure it's the correct answer, but we'll work on that later.

Also, try this method on 20 (not 28!) and see what you get. Using the above methods, you could try to manually tailor a way to get `[[0],[0],[2]]`. It's not a problem if it just works for 20 at first.

If you're feeling adventurous, try to get `[[0],[0],[[0]]]` with the above methods.